# How can I get IIS to redirect to a virtual application if no path is specified?

Tags: iis, url-rewriting, arr

My IIS setup has one site, bound to a domain. Let's call it: www.mydomain.com

The site folder itself is empty. This site hosts multiple  applications and virtual directories. One of the applications is 'portal'.

What I want to do is accept any incoming request for www.mydomain.com or www.mydomain.com/ and redirect it to: www.mydomain.com/portal

I've got ARR and URL Rewrites up and running. I'm just not sure how to configure them for this.

Answer (score 4):

A redirection rule like below will work.

Put the following `web.config` file to your web site's root folder. Or, update the existing one if you have.

```xml
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>
<configuration>
<system.webServer>
    <rewrite>
    <rules>
        <rule name="toPortal" stopProcessing="true">
            <match url="^$" />
            <action type="Redirect" url="/portal" redirectType="Found" />
        </rule>
    </rules>
    </rewrite>
</system.webServer>
</configuration>
```

You may want look at [this tutorial](http://www.iis.net/learn/extensions/url-rewrite-module/creating-rewrite-rules-for-the-url-rewrite-module) to learn how to create url rewrite rules with IIS Manager. These xml nodes are not coming from my brain too.

Comment: Perfect. I was trying way too hard. Thanks!